# New Hologram World with touch and feel, Possible? Land, Water, Fire, Air, Sky with touch and feel Hologram?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, humans, alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-resources

I'm curious if it's possible for humans to create a Hologram World.

**Atmosphere for Hologram World:**

- Touch and feel for all living and non living objects in the world
- Living Hologram objects which will interact with humans
- Land, Water, Fire, Air, Sky with touch and feel for humans

What would be the experience of humans when they first interact with the Hologram world?

Comment: Can you tell in which era (today, near future, far future) this hologram world would be created ? For example the movie Ready Player One has a touch and feel system but it happens in 2045...

Comment: I fail to see what kind of answer you are looking for. If you want an actual hologram nobody can tell you how that works, otherwise we'd have that. Your question is very unclear and I can't imagine what would even answer that.

Comment: @Goufalite . In the Near future , with all classical elements (land, Air, Water, Sky, Wind). If we could touch and feel all these classical elements then that would be the best part for humans

Comment: @ArtificialSoul I want to know whether it is possible to create the classical elements and give touch feel rather than how it works. Also interested to know how it will be for humans to experience the new Hologram world.

Comment: The `reality-check` tag seems more appropriate for the subject and the question than the `science-based` tag. `science-based` says you want citations and discussion of how it might work.

Comment: In what tradition are land, air, water, sky, and wind "the classical elements"? For example, in the European tradition the classical elements are earth, water, air and fire, to which [aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_(classical_element)) is often added as a [fifth element](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quintessence).

Comment: Please have some consideration for people unfamiliar with your work. Please explain what those elements have to do with holograms, what you do with those holograms and how people interact with them like you would to someone who doesn't know anything. Start at the beginning and then end with a clear question. That's also good practice for when you write your story

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [Holodeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holodeck)

[image: An idle holodeck]

Given your description, you've already answered your own question *What would be the experience of humans when they first interact with the Hologram world?*

The answer is "It would be indistinguishable from the real world."

There would be wonder, much talk of it's potential as an educational medium, but it will mostly be used for interactive pornography, which will drive down the price for the technology, opening it up for those other more noble uses.